# .net Core One to Many Relationship too slow

Tags: sql-server, one-to-many, asp.net-core-3.1

I've a .netcore application where I set the table up as follows within my PortalDBContext.OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
   .HasMany(p => p.Childs)
   .WithOne(c=> c.Parent)
   .HasForeignKey(c=> c.ParentId);
```

The `Parent` Class has a PK id of a GUID and

```
public ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }
```

The `Child` Class has a PK id of a GUID and

```
public virtual Guid ParentId { get; set; }
```

The SQL Profiler shows the SQL takes 0.8 of a second to run locally.
The tables have only a hand full of rows each.
The call in code takes 1min 40sec

```
var context = this._dbContextProvider.GetDbContext();
var query = context.Parent.Include(p => p.Childs)
                .Where(c=> c.Id == ParentId);
return await query.ToListAsync();
```

I am not sure why the call takes so long.  Other calls in the app only take a second or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue with the above. However **one of the columns in the DB was large**. It held the result of an editor which can include very large images. `src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo...`
When I remove the data from that column it runs as fast as normal.

However the difference is vast.

SQL with the large data=0.8 seconds.
.Net Core bringing back the results 1min 40.

Perhaps its because SQL cuts off some text when its displaying something that is 13,000,000 in DATALENGTH.

Comment: SSMS, not SQL, does truncate long blobs. SSMS is just a client application as far as SQL Server is concerned.  Loading 13MB over the network is slow no matter what. Just don't load those columns if you don't need them.

Comment: You are correct @PanagiotisKanavos about SSMS. The columns for me are needed. I think my solution will need to convert those base64 images into jpg images in Azure Storage.